# Read cell value python

Tags: python, openpyxl, xlrd

I use below code for read excel, is it possible read only cell "C13" or "A9"

```
file = self.excel_file.decode('base64')

excel_fileobj = TemporaryFile('wb+')
excel_fileobj.write(file)
excel_fileobj.seek(0)

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_fileobj, data_only=True)

sheet = workbook[workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]]

for row in sheet.rows:
            print(row[1].value)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried:

```
print(str(sheet['C13'].value))
print(str(sheet['A9'].value))
```